# Fragment onCreateView Called but doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I have Activity with fragment A. When I click to some view I need to show another fragment B.

I show the fragment(A) the following way.

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, FragmentA(), "FragmentA")
    .commit()
```

This is how I show up Fragment(B)

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, FragmentB(), "FragmentB")
    .addToBackStack("FragmentA")
    .commit()
```

But **sometimes** when *I call many times* `showFragmentB() -> popBackStack()` Fragment(B) stops showing, but at the same time I see in logs that `onCreateView` is Called, but fragment doesn't show up

Comment: you want to view FragmentA  on backpress of fragmentB ?

Comment: @sasikumar Yes, I want

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead..Replace your below code..

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, FragmentB(), "FragmentB")
.addToBackStack("FragmentA")
.commit()
```

With this code..It's working

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, FragmentB(), "FragmentB")
    .addToBackStack("FragmentA")
    .commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragmentActivity add

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){    
if (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount > 0) {        
    fm.popBackStack();
} else {        
    super.onBackPressed();  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
YOUR_FRAGMENT fragment3 = new YOUR_FRAGMENT ();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

then if you need back  press

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```